# Selenium IDE Store command

Tags: selenium, ide, selenium-ide

can we declare a variable in one test case using **"Store"** command and use globally in another test case of the same test suite.

---

**My Question is how can we use variable globally in Selenium IDE ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found some articles which help you for the same :-

http://qafriend.com/selenium/storage-or-global-variable-in-selenium

https://willcodefor.wordpress.com/2013/05/07/creating-global-variables-in-selenium-ide/

Hope it will help you

Comment: Thank you @Shubham Jain.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is Yes

You can use `store` command in one test case and use its value in another test

Format is

```
Command : store
Target : 9999999999
Value : username
```

And This is how you can access it:

`${username}`

Example : suppose i have to perform login in some testcase so here i will store username and password  at one testcase using `store`  and whenever i required i will use in following manner :

```
Command : type
Target : id=MobileNo
Value : ${username}
```